# Происхождение слова "винегрет"

Tags: этимология

По идее, винегрет - традиционное русское блюдо. Но у меня ощущение, что слово это совсем не русское. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: В винегрете , насколько известно , важной составной частью является нарезанный кубиками отварной картофель . Картофель не есть "русский" овощ . Картофель попал в Россию только при Петре I-м , а распространение получил ещё позднее . Версия РУССКИЙ САЛАТ , от ВЕНЕ=РУССКИЙ выглядит несостоятельно .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Французское. Там оно обозначает не весь салат, а только соус из уксуса и масла.

Answer (score -1):

ВИНЕГРЕТ: ВИН-ВЕН - связка, сравним ВЕНик, ВЕНок, ВЕНзель. ГРЕТ - градация, ср. град, ограда, гравий, грамм, граната - всё, что состоит из маленьких частиц.  Даже слово ГРАМОТА - состоит из маленьких частиц - букв. Связка инГРАДиентов.
Поэтому слова ВИНЕГРЕТ и ВИНОГРАД так похожи. Предположение, что слово ВИНЕГРЕТ произошло от слова ВИНО, якобы потому что туда добавляется уксус от сбродившего вина, является ложным.